# Is it possible to add records to oData model so it'll be visible on UI and without posting?

Tags: odata, sapui5, crud

I'm working on a project using `oData` CRUD.

I have a list of tasks in which the user should be able to add records and work on them and only then send it to backend.

Is it possible to add records to the model so it will be presented to user without posting?

Meaning by doing the following:

```
var oContext = oModel.createEntry("/Products", {
  properties: {
    ID: inId,
    Name: "Product",
    Description: "new Product",
    ReleaseDate: new Date(),
    Price: "10.1",
    Rating: 1,
    __metadata: {
      type: "ODataDemo.Product",
      uri: "https://services.odata.org/(S(ylyrw0pnsmd5gc0wixqxkawj))/V2/OData/OData.svc/Products(" + inId + ")"
    }
  }
});
```

And not performing oModel.submitChanges().

so that the records will appear on the list

Thanks a lot!

Meirav.

Comment: Related enhancement request: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2433

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a necessity of doing oModel.create until you do not have to post the data to the backend. If you use, two-way binding, the UI changes get reflected in the model directly and you can then finally post them.

Also, you can prepare the final body(to be sent in the request) before doing the create operation.